# Chat application in android using xmpp

Tags: android, configuration, xmpp, chat, server

What should I do to developer a chat application in android using XMPP over server   Please tell the whole process, configuration step over server and in application also And please tell me the right way if I am wrong by using XMPP. Thanks in advance

Comment: https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/ccs.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use GCM? You can send a payload up to 4kb as in a message. And the service is free.

https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html

Comment: Is it possible to send video and images etc by GCM?

Comment: No but you could use app engine to store your content and send the data to retrieve it with gcm

Comment: Have a look at endpoints, datastore and cloud sql

Comment: cool I will try thanks but still if you have any idea about xmpp and about Smack and its configuration then please tell me.

Comment: This may be of interest to you https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/ccs.html